# Equivalence between definitions of measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I found in a book that they define a measurable function in the following way:

**Definition 1:**

Consider the measure space $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$.

A function $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be measurable if, for every $α \in \mathbb{R},
\{x \in X : f(x) > \alpha\} \in \Sigma$.

The definition I knew was that

**Definition 2 :**

A function is measurable if the pre-image of every measurable set is measurable.

**How come these definitions are equivalent?**
I suspect it has something to do with the fact that half-lines are generators of the Borel sigma algebra, but I haven't been able to prove it.

I guess the implication 2 -> 1 is trivial. If a function is measurable, half lines being borel sets, are measurable sets on $\mathbb{R}$, therefore their preimages are measurable

Can someone tell me if I am on the right track and complete the proof?

Comment: It does. Given any function $f : X \to Y$, prove that $\{S \subseteq Y \mid f^{-1}(S)$ is measurable$\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Note that if this algebra contains all the half-lines, it must contain all Borel sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{H}$ denote the collection of half lines.

We know they generate the Borel sigma-algebra, i.e. $\sigma(\mathcal{H}) = \mathcal{B}$, so the preimages of measurable sets are $$f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}) = f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal{H})).$$

We also know $f^{-1}(\mathcal{H}) \subseteq \Sigma$, which implies $$\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{H})) \subseteq \Sigma.$$

Thus, if we show
$$f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal{H})) = \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{H})), \tag{$*$}$$
then we are done, since we would then have $f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}) \subseteq \Sigma$. Try showing this last claim yourself; if you are stuck, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/624145/43949).

Comment: Is this the proof of  the implication 1 -> 2?. So is my proof of implication 2 -> 1 correct or is there anything missing?

Comment: Is $f^{-1}(\mathcal{H}) \subseteq \Sigma$   the hypothesis ?(that is definition 1?)

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Yes, you were correct that 2 -> 1 is trivial. Yes, $f^{-1}(\mathcal{H}) \subseteq \Sigma$ is the hypothesis in 1.

Comment: I m copying here part of the prove in the linked post:   The "$\subseteq$" is not immediately obvious. Let us denote by ${\cal G}$ the collection of all sets $G\subseteq \Omega_2$ such that $f^{-1}(G) \in \sigma(f^{-1}({\cal C}))$. We note that ${\cal G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and that ${\cal C}\subseteq {\cal G}$, so $\sigma({\cal C})\subseteq {\cal G}$ (again by minimality of generated  $\sigma$-algebra). This means $f^{-1}(\sigma({\cal C})) \subseteq  \sigma(f^{-1}({\cal C}))$.

Comment: Could you please explain it in more detail ?, I don't understant at all the last two sentences. Like ${\cal G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra,  ${\cal C}\subseteq {\cal G}$ and $f^{-1}(\sigma({\cal C})) \subseteq  \sigma(f^{-1}({\cal C}))$