# Are measurable functions surjective?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

I learned that a measurable function can be defined as:

Let ( X, Σ ) and ( Y, T ) be two measurable spaces. A function f: X → Y is called measurable if for every E ∈ T  the pre-image of E under f is in Σ.

I read that f doesn't have to be surjective, but couldn't find why:

Given the definition, $f^{-1}(Y) \in Σ$.
Since every $E \in\Sigma$ is a subset of $X$, $f^{-1}(Y) = \{x\in X|f(x)\in Y\}  \subset X$. Doesn't that mean that for any $y \in Y$ there $\exists x: f(x)=y$ and therefore f is surjective?
Also, doesn't this mean that $f(X)=Y$?

Where did I make a mistake here?

Comment: Remind yourself what the definition of $f^{-1}(E)$ and in particular of $f^{-1}(Y)$ is

Comment: Consider a simple counter-example first. Suppose that $(X, \Sigma) = (Y, T) = (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})).$ Then consider the function $f(x) = 1.$ Can you convince yourself that $f$ is measurable (and of course not surjective)?

Comment: In fact, $f^{-1}(Y)=X$ is always true. *That does not mean $f(X)=Y$*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to revise the definition of surjective and function,
$f^{-1}(Y) \subset X $ is true for any function. The notation $f^{-1}(Y)$ means: the elements of $X$ that land in $Y$ when $f$ is applied. But $Y$ is the image of $f$, all elements of $X$ land in $Y$! What you really want for $f$ to be surjective is that $f(X)=Y$. The two things are not the same. Just try to picture in your head what happens with a constant function.

Comment: Oh right - thanks for the clarification, I really got stuck at some point there.

But if a measurable function isn't subjective, does that mean that p.e. in the case of probability theory, its law $P_f(y \in Y) $doesn't have to be a proper probability measure on (Y, T), since $P(X) = 1$ and f(Y) doesn't have to be X?

Comment: Indeed, the push-forward of a measure does not have to be a measure. What is always a measure is the pullback measure on $Y$: if $A \subset Y$ is measurable, we can define a new measure $f^\ast \mu (A):=\mu (f^{-1}(A))$. This is a measure on $Y$, and note that here $\mu$ is the measure on $X$.

Comment: That makes sense. So that means $\{f^{-1}(A) | A \in T\}$ is itself a sigma-algebra?

Comment: No, note that the sigma algebra for the pullback is still $T$.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for all the help!

Comment: I reflected on the topic for a bit and have two questions left:
> If f: ( X, Σ ) -> ( Y, T ) is a measurable function, $f^{-1}(T)$ could be $\varnothing$ since $\varnothing$ is part of every sigma algebra over a space by definition, right?
and the other one:
> When we refer to a sigma-algebra generated by f / the pullback sigma algebra $\{f^{-1}(A):A\in T \}$, is this only a name? The pullback sigma algebra doesn't have to be an actual sigma-algebra on the space it gets mapped back to?

Comment: The answer to the first question is yes! In general it is possible to have a non-empty set with zero measure or probability. The pullback of a $\sigma$-algebra is itself a $\sigma$-algebra. This is proved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211390/is-the-pull-back-of-a-generated-sigma-algebra-itself-a-generated-sigma-alg